# CSV.generate adds quotation marks to strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, csv

I am generating CSV files this way:

```
csv_address_book = CSV.generate do |csv|
  @users.each do |u|  
    csv << ["Add", 
            nil,
            u.name,
            u.pet,
            nil,
            u.addreess,
            ..]
```

It works well, but to some strings are attached quotation marks, so instead of:

```
A,Cat,123,B
```

I am getting

```
A,"Cat",123,B
```

I am trying to get rid of this behavior, but I am losing so far... The string **Cat** is loaded from database and there are no quotation marks.
I've tried manually remove them, like

```
d.pet.gsub('"', '')
```

But the result is the same - the quotation marks are still in the final generated CSV file.

Any tip how to get rid of it?

Comment: Could you tell us what `[...]` and `d.pet` contain? From the information you are giving us, the `gsub` should work.

Comment: The part **[...]** represents variables containing data from database, there's like 25-30 columns in the CSV file, so I just shorten it here.

Comment: We need to see the minimal code that can duplicate this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing the problem using some simple Ruby code to poke at CSV:

```
require 'csv'

['A','Cat',123,'B'].to_csv # => "A,Cat,123,B\n"
```

If I break down the generation CSV seems to be behaving well:

```
['a', 'b'].to_csv # => "a,b\n"
['a b'].to_csv # => "a b\n"
['a,b'].to_csv # => "\"a,b\"\n"
['"a b"'].to_csv # => "\"\"\"a b\"\"\"\n"
```

Recreating your code using `generate` and a block:

```
csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << ['A','Cat',123,'B']
  csv << ['a', 'b']
  csv << ['a b']
  csv << ['a,b']
  csv << ['"a b"']
end

csv_string
# => "A,Cat,123,B\na,b\na b\n\"a,b\"\n\"\"\"a b\"\"\"\n"

puts csv_string
# >> A,Cat,123,B
# >> a,b
# >> a b
# >> "a,b"
# >> """a b"""
```